# what happens if I accept an answer and later accept a different one?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer, unaccepted-answer

1. Does the first user lose the reputation points he/she had earned?
2. If not, is he/she somehow informed that I changed my mind and accepted a different answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the originally accepted user will lose the 15 points he gained. Yes, he'll be notified about that in the reputation notification widget doohickey at the top of every page with the reason "unaccept".

[image]

Comment: But only if the unaccept took place on a later day. Accept, then Unaccept again *on the same day* clears the reputation notice in the reputation tab. Same for an unaccept, then re-accept pair on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes.
2. They can see the reputation change.  There are no other notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Yes to both questions. The original answer's author loses the points and is informed that he or she lost the points and why.