# Morals - Accepting Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer, late-answers, multiple-answers

Let's say I post a question and someone answers it. The answer does fix my problem but it's just a short, not-really-explaining-much answer. I accept it anyways, since it helped me solve my problem.

If then, someone else posts an answer to that same question (remember: I already accepted the other one) which does explain a lot and more or less contains the first answer, should I re-accept? So should I accept the second answer and give the first an up vote?

What do you think?

Comment: see also: [what happens if I accept an answer and later accept a different one?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256484/what-happens-if-i-accept-an-answer-and-later-accept-a-different-one)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per the [help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) says, (emphasis mine)

> As the author of the question, you have an additional option: accepting an answer that **you believe is the best solution to your problem**.

So, apparently, in your case, it is a time dependent matter. First, you accept the-then *best* answer. Later, if you get a *better than the best* answer which replies to yours question with more details and clarity, please feel free to re-accept.

Note: You can always upvote **all** the helpful answers. IMHO, that's the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here. :-)